# Rank Value getting different,while Give same boosting value in solr query

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrj, lucene

i have 3 field in my solr index database and i search two queries but different field

***Indexed data***

> **employeeid** : 220232
>
> **pskills** : JSP, Servlets, HTML, Java
>
> **oskills** : DB2, Oracle, JDBC, JNI, JSP, VC++, C, C++, Java, SQL, XML, Palm OS, UNIX, PALM OS, AIX, Linux, Solaris, Windows 2000,
> TCP/IP, IP, IDS, Asset Liability Management, Enterprise Application
> Integration

***schema.xml***

```
<field name="employeeid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="pskills" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />  
<field name="oskills" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
```

> **Query 1** = employeeid : 220232 AND (pskills : ( ( "java" ) )^3000.00)
>
> *Score*:  0.6169528
>
> **Query 2** = employeeid : 220232 AND (oskills : ( ( "java" ) )^3000.00)
>
> *Score*: 0.32307756

My question is Both field having "Java" keyword then why given different value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of reasons!  Particularly:

- If the fields are different lengths, the score will be impacted (matches in shorter fields are weighed more heavily) (*Definitely a factor here*)
- More than one match is found in one of the fields, giving that field a higher tf (say java appears once in oskills, but twice in pskills, for instance) (*Doesn't appear to be the case here, but bears stating*)
- The terms java is more common across all documents in one field than the other.  If, for instance, across all documents, "java" appears in oskills in 1000 documents, but it only appears in pskills in 100 documents, then the match in pskills scores higher due to idf. (*Don't know if this has an effect, since I don't know what's in the rest of the documents*)

For some documentation on lucene scoring, see [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

The scores you get are specific to the query and the state of the index at the time it was run.  They aren't intended to be compared to the scores of other queries.